# post the user text to the server using $.post()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

Hi im updating my page using jQuery/javascript once a user types something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea style="border: 0" cols="77" rows="2">Write Something....</textarea>
<button>Post Message</button>
<div id="test1"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Im trying post the user text to the server using $.post(),i dont know how to handle it on a aspx page on the server that handles those requests, and add the content to mysql db?

If a client requests the updated page, send the page frame as is but use i.e. a repeater or another looping construct to add in the content from the DB. <- unsure how to do this?

Comment: You code seems to be irrelevant to the question. Where are you using $.post() and what do you have in your codebehind?

Comment: im not im trying to post my textarea variables to somewhere can i post to a listbox then i could just save the content of the listbox to mysql?

Comment: What do you mean by `"post to a listbox"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a service, and then direct your post to a service method therein.  You would save the data to your MySQL db from that service method

If you're trying to do this when the user types something, you might look at the keypress event though the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) say this might not be supported on all browsers.

Here's a little helper method I threw together a while ago for that purpose:

```
function runAjax(targetURL, dataInput, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url: targetURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dataInput,
        dataType: "json",
        success: success,
        async: true
    });
}
```

And then:

```
runAjax("yourService.asmx/ServiceMethod", "{Parameter:" + dataFromYourListBox + "}",
            function(data) {
                //update DOM
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125295/how-to-save-div-tag-to-mysql-with-php-and-jquery

Comment: this is more what im looking for but an asp version? Rather than php id like it to send to an aspx page Im unsure how to create a service

Comment: You create a service by right-clicking your website, add new item, then find asmx web service in there.  I believe you can also use jQuery to post to static methods on your page's class - you might try Googling that

Comment: Here's a link on calling static page methods from jQuery  http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/